# Animating external SVG using Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg

I have a JSFiddle of an animated swinging needle meter, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/simon_brooke/0u2vmo86/). It works. However, it works because the SVG is inline in the HTML. I want to use SVG from an external file, using something like

```
<img src="meter.svg">
```

or

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="meter.svg"></object>
```

The problem with both these solutions is that neither the CSS nor the scripts linked from the HTML file can 'see' the elements defined in the linked SVG file. Consequently I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
at Scope.meterApp.controller.$scope.sweep (animate.js:28)
```

and the image appears entirely black.

If I move the script elements from the HTML file to the SVG file, the scripts don't execute at all (in either Chromium 43.0.2357.130 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) or Firefox 40.0.3, which is what I'm testing with just now).

I can apply the same CSS to the SVG file as to the HTML file by adding the following to the top of the SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="animate.css" type="text/css"?>
```

But I can't find a solution for the JavaScript.

Has anyone solved this problem? Is it possible to apply JavaScript to an SVG image linked from an HTML page? In particular is it possible for the same script to act on elements both in the HTML page itself and in the linked SVG?

Comment: Scripts don't execute in `<img>` contexts, they do in `<object>` contexts though. Create a demo to show us how you're embedding the script in the SVG file so we can see where you're going wrong and correct it.